# how to extract attribute from tag xml with c#?

Tags: c#, xml, tags, attributes, xmlserializer

```
<channel>
        <title>test + test</title>
        <link>http://testprog.test.net/api/test</link>
        <description>test.com</description>
        <category>test + test</category>

        <item xml:base="http://test.com/test.html?id=25>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">25</guid>
            <link>http://test.com/link.html</link>
            <title>title test</title>
            <description>Description test description test</description>
            <a10:updated>2015-05-26T10:23:53Z</a10:updated>
            <enclosure type="" url="http://test.com/test/test.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
        </item>
    </channel>
```

I extracted this tag (title test) like this:

```
title = ds.Tables["item"].Rows[0]["title"] as string;
```

how to extract url attribute from `<encosure>` tag with c#?

thx

Comment: Could you please clarify - how this code you've shown `ds.Tables...` is related to xml you've shown? It is related to some `DataTable`, not xml, I suppose.

Comment: create two classes (channel and item), add proper xml tags to the members (attribute or element) and deserialize the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First option**

You can create classes to map and deserialize the XML into object and easily access as properties.

**Second option**

If you are only interested in few values and you don't want to create mapping classes , you can use [XPath](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C), there are many articles and questions anwered that you can easily find.

To extract url attribute from  tag you can use the path:

```
"/channel/item/enclosure/param[@name='url']/@value"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many articles that will help you read XML, but the simple answer is to load your XML into an XML document, and simply call

```
doc.GetElementsByTagName("enclosure")
```

This will return an XmlNodeList with all 'enclosure' tags found in your document. I would really recommend doing some reading about using XML to make sure your application is functional and robust.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinqToXML and this will be better useful for you...

please refer the code

```
string xml = @"<channel>
            <title>test + test</title>
            <link>http://testprog.test.net/api/test</link>
            <description>test.com</description>
            <category>test + test</category>

            <item xml:base=""http://test.com/test.html?id=25"">
                <guid isPermaLink=""false"">25</guid>
                <link>http://test.com/link.html</link>
                <title>title test</title>
                <description>Description test description test</description>
                <a10>2015-05-26T10:23:53Z</a10>
                <enclosure type="""" url=""http://anupshah.com/test/test.jpg"" width=""200"" height=""200""/>
            </item>
        </channel>";

        var str = XElement.Parse(xml);


        var result = (from myConfig in str.Elements("item")
                     select myConfig.Elements("enclosure").Attributes("url").SingleOrDefault())
                     .First();

        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

I hope it will help you...